# Unexpected identifier - how functions works

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a small simple jquery function but i can't understand how to solvethis problem and can't find simple resources online where to read how to create simple functions with two variables.
My code is

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    function infoText(menuitem,textinfo) {
        menuitem.click(function(){
            textinfo.fadeIn(300);
        }
    }

    infoText('.come-realizzo','#come-realizzo');
    infoText('.works','#works');

});
```

When i call the function i get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on 9 line (
>   infoText('.come-realizzo','#come-realizzo'); ).

Thanks!

Comment: You're missing a parenthesis on the line after `textinfo.fadeIn(300);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a closing paren at the end of the click handler function.

You actual will not work because you are not referencing a jQuery object in the `infoText` function, two possible solutions:

- pass jQuery objects as params
- from passed string get the jQuery object

First:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    function infoText($menuitem,$textinfo) {
        $menuitem.click(function(){
            $textinfo.fadeIn(300);
        });
    }

    infoText($('.come-realizzo'),$('#come-realizzo'));
    infoText($('.works'),$('#works'));

});
```

Second:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    function infoText(menuitem,textinfo) {
        $(menuitem).click(function(){
            $(textinfo).fadeIn(300);
        });
    }

    infoText('.come-realizzo','#come-realizzo');
    infoText('.works','#works');

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a string, you need to convert them into a jquery object using `$(/*selector*/)` like this below

Change

```
menuitem.click(function () {
  textinfo.fadeIn(300);
}
```

to

```
$(menuitem).click({
  $(textinfo).fadeIn(300);
});
 ^ missing to close the click function
```

Comment: For a *useful* answer, say *what* you changed (rather than making someone hunt around for the extra paren and such) and *why*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah i should've added that in the start, edited the answer thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing string instead of identifier ,use the below code

```
infoText($('.come-realizzo'),$('#come-realizzo') );
```

OR this other solution if you want to pass text instead of selector to your function

```
  $( menuitem).click(function(){
  $( textinfo).fadeIn(300);
```

Comment: There's a syntax error in `infoText` that's probably the more significant problem.

Comment: but his main problem is passing string instead of identifier

Comment: @ sino: I would say that a syntax error preventing the script from even being evaluated is the "main" problem. But yes, *both* have to be fixed for it to work.